# C3 Charts in C# html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, c3.js

Recently im working on c3 charts its actually working great
but i had a problem with dynamically get multiple data in DB

[Multiple XY Lines chart](https://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy_multiple.html)
[X had to be in string](https://c3js.org/samples/categorized.html)

> I actually want multiple xy values and x values had to be string
> After a long period i dont get any ideas

I tried json method in ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Home/timechart",
                data: Getdata,
                contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    successClass(response)
                },
            });

            function successClass(jsondata) {
                var data = {};
                var mvalue = [];
                var mdatetime = [];
                var TagID = [];


                jsondata.forEach(function (e) {
                    mvalue.push(e.mvalue);
                    mdatetime.push(e.mdatetime);
                    if (TagID != e.TagID) {
                        TagID.push(e.TagID);
                    }

                })

                //alert(objvalue)
                // alert(objdate)
                var chart = c3.generate({
                    bindto: '#chart',


                    data: {



                        columns: [

                            /* ['x'].concat(mdatetime),*/
                            [TagID].concat(mvalue)


                        ]

                    },
                    axis: {
                        x: {
                            type: 'category',
                            categories: mdatetime,
                            tick: {
                                rotate: -25,
                                multiline: false
                            },
                            
                            height: 130
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'outer-center'
                    }

                });

            }
        }
    });

});
```

> i can get a chart in single dynamic value but dont know how to get multiple y values and same x value in it

Comment: `how to get multiple y values and same x value in it`Do you mean you want to add multiple arrays into `columns`?like [this](https://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html)?

Comment: yes @YiyiYou but i want x value as string(dynamically from table) and multiple y values with separate y names.. i want all of them dynamically

Comment: `i want all of them dynamically`If so,you need to add dynamic arrays into columns,and add dynamic arraus into `categories`,you need to pass the arrays from backend to your frontend.